# Convert PL/SQL to Hive QL

Tags: plsql, hadoop, hive, bigdata

I want a tool through which I can get the respective hive query by giving the PL/SQL query. There are lots of tools available which convert sql to hql. ie: taod for cloude database. But it does not show me the respective hive query.

Is there any such kind of tool whose convert given sql to hql. Please help me.

Thanks and Regards,
Ratan

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at open-source project PL/HQL at http://www.hplsql.org/ which is now a part of Hive 2.x or higher version. It allows you to run existing SQL Server, Oracle, Teradata, MySQL etc. stored procedures in Hive.

Answer (score 1):

Ratan, I did not how to start responding. So, lets start like this. I think you checked toad and thinking like there is a tool to convert SQL to hive QL. I do not think there is such a tool.

Let me clarify like this, HIVE QL, is same as SQL. Check this links before you are trying to write some queries:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual,

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF.

This is simple to understand if you know sql and simple to write (as you check the HIve ql).

Hive doesnot have many operators the sql supports. For example:

`select * from sales where country like 'EU~%';` "HIVE SUPPORTS LIKE"

But try this negative queries as we write in SQL :

`select * from sales where country not like 'EU~%';` "HIVE DOES NOT SUPPORT"

This is just one example, I remember. There are more like this. But to deal with these hive has many like "where not" etc.

If your question is does the Hive have any PL/SQL support. Straight answer is no. But, we can check the UDF in hive and also, the PIG on Hadoop.