# ANSI SQL PORTABILITY TO HADOOP HIVE conversion tool or macro

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, ansi-sql, hiveql

I am working on hadoop hive solutions. My requirement is to convert ansi sql queries to hive queries by using a tool or excel macro. Is there any tool/macro exist? if yes, what are they; if not need suggestions to implement it. Is this possible? Do we have alternative sql queries in Hive for DMLs (like insert,update ... )? What are the pros and cons?

Any suggestions is highly appreciated....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert PL/SQL to Hive QL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074010/convert-pl-sql-to-hive-ql)

Answer (score 3):

I do not think that whole ANSI sql can be ported to hive because it does not support joins different from equ-join. So such SQL can not be ported. 
Another point - there is no updates in hive - data is read only... 
The rest looks very similar to ANSI SQL and I would suggest to try running queries as-is.

Comment: This is correct - just want to add that there's a good reason that a tool doesn't exist: ANSI SQL and Hive were designed for very different purposes. Much of the SQL standard is for OLTP-type purposes: inserting individual records, updates, deletes, key constraints, etc. Hive was designed for purely batch processing, with a query language similar to SQL to minimize the overhead of learning a new language. Hive is NOT intended to replace a traditional SQL database, and if you try to use it that way, it's going to be painful.

Comment: as you said is correct. But to achieve DML operations we have an alternate way (check it https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-dml.html). I dont know how far we can achieve DML operations, but i think there is a way.