# SQL to HiveQL generator

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

Is there any way to convert my SQL queries to Hive queries, or any open-source tool or project which can help me to convert some queries from SQL to HiveQL so that I can start my development by querying in the Hadoop database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert PL/SQL to Hive QL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074010/convert-pl-sql-to-hive-ql)

Answer (score 1):

HiveQL is SQL-like language for data warehouse teams migrating to Hadoop, because it
gives them a familiar SQL language that hides the complexity of MR programming.Hive does not support the full SQL-92 specification and the missing specification can be easily workaround in Hive.Hive has some extensions that are not in SQL-92 and these extensions were inspired by Mapreduce.HiveQL most closely resembles MySQL’s SQL dialect.

Answer (score 1):

No and it does not make very much sense.

Every RDBMS has slightly different SQL - even those statements that are in specification. And HiveQL is unique in its own way too.

Also Hive does not provide all features offered by RDBMS, however it's catching up.

You will have to become familiar with HiveQL to translate queries. And translating would basically be copying and modifying, especially if you are using MySQL which should be the closest.

Answer (score 0):

HiveQL is not completely different from SQL. HiveQL is a subset of ANSI SQL with some extensions. More details about the [HiveQL](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual) here. AFAIK, there is no tool for the conversion, documentation should help.